# Is it possible to continue when you hit a BadZipFile?

Tags: python, zip

This zip-file contains 130.000 images.

Is it possible to continue when you run into a BadZipFile?

I mean ignore the bad image and move on to the next.

```py
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile("/content/train.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("/content/train/")
```

The error:

```py
BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'calvary-andrea-mantegna.jpg
```

I want something like this to work.

```py
import zipfile
from zipfile import BadZipfile
try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile("/content/train.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
      zip_ref.extractall("/content/train/")
except BadZipfile:
    continue
```

But i know i cant use a continue in a try-except.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You could could get the "directory" of the ZipFile and extract each member individually in a loop, where your `continue` would make perfect sense.

Comment: Maybe you can use https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist to get all the files inside the zip and then call https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract on each member of the zip?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract files one by one. This may not work, depending what corrupted the file. For instance, if a block of the file was lost somewhere in the middle of the file, all unzips after that will fail.

```
import zipfile

try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile("/content/train.zip", 'r') as zip_ref:
        for info in zip_ref.infolist():
            try:
                zip_ref.extract(info, path="/content/train/")
            except zipfile.BadZipFile as e:
                print(f"{e} - offset {info.header_offset}")
except zipfile.BadZipFile as e:
    print(f"could not read zipfile: {e}")
```

Comment: This looked promising until i ran into error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid stored block lengths.

Comment: I have all the files in a folder on my hard drive but need to compress it to use it in google colab. I have tried zipfile, tarfile, shutil.make_archive but 
unfortunately i often run into errors when trying to unpack.

Comment: Just speculating, but this may be a problem with zip vs zip64 - an update to zip that handles large files. Before zip64, you could have at most 64K files, and a total archive size of 4Gig. I don't know the details of the python implementation. If you have an external zip utility that handles zip64, run it with `subprocess` to see if it works.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i am zipping it on my hard drive, uploading it to google drive, clean the data in Colab, zipping it again, and then unzipping it before i use it with my machine learning model. Something i should try is to clean it locally and then do as you say. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: That should work, though. When uploading and downloading, you could also take an md5 hash of the file to make sure it survives the transfer.